# Where are the “dollar index” stats for my content in the new version (V5) of Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I found the "$ index" for each web page to be one of the most useful features in Google Analytics, but I can't use the new version (V5) that was rolled out a few months ago, because that statistic is now gone. Has it been removed? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a comment on this blog post it is coming but just not there yet

http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/03/new-google-analytics-quick-insights.html

> Regarding functionality that was "removed," the new version doesn't have all the features of the old version yet, but they're coming soon. $ Index should make it's way to the new version, but it's not there yet.

Answer (score 2):

`$/index` has been removed from the v5 beta. It's not clear if its a temporary removal, or if its been eliminated entirely.

I think the concern had been that it was too confusing of a metric for people to understand.